# Google Tango tracking accuracy versus motion speed

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I am currently trying to develop a solution for a Roller Coaster rides manufacturer, where he wants to add a VR experience to his Roller Coaster.

So I stumbled across a problem where syncing a mobile headset with the motion of the ride is not an easy task to achieve. So I thought about using Google's project tango enabled device to tackle this problem. So can I rely on the capabilities of Tango's positional tracking to solve this issue given that a roller coaster ride may move at great speeds. So will the motion tracking handle this kind of speed motion situation ?

Comment: I doubt anyone has tried using it on a roller coaster.  Even if it can, it may not be able to handle corkscrews and loops, and the probability anyone else here has ever tried is very nearly 0.  I think you're going to need to test this out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be easy even using the project tango because it updates your position almost 100 times a second, you can change this to around 1000 times a second.  You might still run into problems since the Tango uses probabilities at being in a certain locations and if your going really fast the position you are in in your virtual environment might glitch to a different point.  Test it out and lets see :).

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure that a tango could help since a good part of it's magic is from depth and  environmental features which looking out from a car on a roller coaster will be  lacking. perhaps a high speed camera that also records gps co-ordinates extremely fast would give you a template from which to map events onto specific locations in the ride. being able to replay the ride in slow motion will help you decide what events you can place where in the ride. from that point you create the AR events. then you need to find a method of feeding the created events to the goggles. but it ends up being a video with some real life bleed-though with a separate feed for each rider of the coaster since only 2 riders are basically in the same spot at the same time and the feed is location based. and i'm not sure that is what you are looking for. good luck with the project.